# How to Delete AD Group

Tags: c#, active-directory

**Question :**
How do I delete a group from active directory?

---

**What I have tried:**

*1. PrinipalContext*

I am trying to delete an active directory group. I have this right now:

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, myDomain, ldapUser, ldapPassword))
{
    var group1 = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, groupName);
    group1.Delete();
}
```

But I get an error: `"Unpersisted Principal objects can not be deleted."`

That lead me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860772/groupprincipal-members-remove-doesnt-work-with-a-large-ad-group), but I don't know what the `invoke` magic is all about and it scares me a little bit.

*2. DirectoryEntry*

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#33

But I just kept getting `"The server is not operational"` errors.

**I just need to delete the AD group, is it even possible?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the DirectoryEntry works fine, but my ldap urls were wrong. Here is the code that I ended up using:

```
using (var ou = new DirectoryEntry(ouPath, ldapUser, ldapPassword))
{
     using (var group = new DirectoryEntry(groupPath, ldapUser, ldapPassword))
     {
          ou.Children.Remove(group);
          group.CommitChanges();
     }
}
```

*WRONG OLD VALUES*

**ouPath** `LDAP://myDomain.local/OU=myTier1,DC=myDomain,DC=local`

**groupPath** `LDAP://groupname/OU=myTier3,OU=myTier2,OU=myTier1,DC=myDomain,DC=local`

*CORRECT NEW VALUES*

**ouPath** `LDAP://myDomain.local/OU=myTier2,OU=myTier1,DC=myDomain,DC=local`

**groupPath** `LDAP://myDomain.local/CN=groupName,OU=myTier3,OU=myTier2,OU=myTier1,DC=myDomain,DC=local`